# Connection refused from outside Vagrant box with private network

Tags: centos, nginx, vagrant

I've set up CentOS 6 on a vagrant box with a private network IP. I can ssh into the box using the IP, so that is working. However, I get a Connection refused on port 80 when curl'ing it. There's a very basic nginx serving up its default welcome page inside. Curling it from inside the box works.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "Centos-6.3-minimal"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7225008/Vagrant/CentOS-6.3-x86_64-minimal.box"

  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.44"
  config.vm.hostname = "local.example.com"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
  end
end
```

Here are some things I have tried:

- Changing to port forwarding 80 -> 8080. Curling on `localhost:8080` just hangs there.
- Trying another IP address. No difference.
- Opening a `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` on the server that is known to listen on `0.0.0.0`. Still getting Connection refused.

These things are known to work:

- SSHing in to the server using the given private network IP works.
- Curling from inside the box works.
- The same setup works on a real server.

I've got Guest Additions installed, but their versions are different on guest and host. That might be the problem. But then why does SSH work, and not port 80? This is the output when I do `vagrant reload`: https://gist.github.com/magnars/496e553f07ad5c770c54

## Update

While this does not work:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
```

This does:

```
ssh -f deploy@local.example.com -L 8080:127.0.0.1:80 -N
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there are many things that could be wrong, the first one to check is the firewall inside the guest: it could be as simple as it having a rule for port 22 but not port 80.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But isn't this precluded from the fact that the exact same setup (provisioned) works fine on a real server?

Comment: depends what you mean by the same setup I suppose.  remember that vagrant boxes aren't identical to clean installs of the upstream OS.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a good point of course. So the minimal centos box that I'm using might have a firewall running. How would I go about finding that out?

Comment: Okay, I'm seeing that iptables is a common centos firewall that come with all versions. Looking into that.

Comment: Indeed. My minimal centos box had iptables running only open on port 22. No such thing on the server OS. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem solved by disable the firewall in guest host

```
sudo service iptables stop
sudo service ip6tables stop
```

And you can use `iptables --list` to check

```
[vagrant@c6401 ~]$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```